# Prevent a specific dll from loading in IIS

Tags: c#, c++, iis-7

I am getting the common error of:

> Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies. The
>   specified module could not be found.

The issue is this dll references unmanaged dlls so it will never be able to load properly. I just want IIS to ignore this file.

I'm playing around with the `<remove assembly>` tag in the web.config, but with no luck.

Any suggestions on how I can prevent my one dll from loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I couldn't figure out a way to limit a specific assembly, I was able to accomplish it by removing all assemblies and adding the specific ones back that I needed. changing the web.config file to:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <remove assembly="*"/>
            <add assembly="example.dll"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This solved my problem of not being able to "late load" DLLs. All you need to do is remove all like you did over and add the web project DLL to the list. That will make the project run and you can implement your own assemblyloading in Application_Start in global.asax for loading the rest of the DLLs needed. With your own loader you can handle the error yourself or ignore it. Might even solve issues with native DLLs inside the bin folder. Just set the PATH environment variable in Application_Start to the bin folder and start loading the rest of the DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

.Net runtime does not load assemblies for fun. It only does so when it is needed - i.e. you are actively using class/methods from that assembly. You may even reference assemblies that are not present as long as code that uses them is not executed.

So preventing the assembly from being loaded will not make your application to work - i.e. remove the assembly and see your application to crush due to missing dependency.

If you are loading assemblies yourself in some way (like Assembly.Load) than you need to figure out how to skip such assemblies...

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case, for me... I need the assembly to be there for a separate process. I can delete it and my web app will run perfectly fine within IIS, but I need the dll there for an install and uninstall action

Comment: @declyne, Have you debug it to figure out who tries to load the assembly?

Comment: Yeah, before my application even enters the Application_Start, IIS tries to load it.

Comment: Yes, I know this is an old thread, but this is still the case.  From self-hosting a Web Api project, Microsoft.Owin.* chooses to load all DLLs in the directory.

Comment: @Dan if you have new question - ask one (linking to existing question like this will demonstrate research you've done). If you just adding yet another case when one loaded all assemblies - sure, many people like to load all assemblies just for fun (including company I work for). To get it fixed you need to contact owners of code.